# Не могу во втором окне получить текущее значение label, которое передается из первого окна

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel

Помогите разобраться, работаю с *PyQT5* и с *Qt Designer*. 
Есть два окна, я передаю значение из `ComboBox` первого окна в `label` второго окна, это без проблем.

Дальше мне нужно получить это значение во втором окне из `label` и провести с ним некоторые манипуляции, но при попытке его получить, мне всегда возвращается его изначальное значение, как будто на форму оно и не передалось.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from SecondWindow import SecondWindowView


class Ui_FirstWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, FirstWindow):
        FirstWindow.setObjectName("FirstWindow")
        FirstWindow.resize(313, 375)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(FirstWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 60, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 200, 141, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        FirstWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(FirstWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        FirstWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(FirstWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FirstWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, FirstWindow):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       FirstWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("FirstWindow", "MainWindow"))
       self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("FirstWindow", "User1"))
       self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("FirstWindow", "User2"))
       self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("FirstWindow", "User3"))
       self.pushButton.setText(_translate("FirstWindow", "SendData"))


class FirstWindowView(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_FirstWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_second_window)

    def open_second_window(self):
       self.sw = SecondWindowView()
       val = self.comboBox.currentText()
       self.sw.label_get_user.setText(val)
       self.hide()
       self.sw.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    fw = FirstWindowView()
    fw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**SecondWindow.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, SecondWindow):
        SecondWindow.setObjectName("SecondWindow")
        SecondWindow.resize(320, 384)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SecondWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_user = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_user.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 71, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_user.setFont(font)
        self.label_user.setObjectName("label_user")
        self.label_get_user = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_get_user.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 70, 251, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_get_user.setFont(font)
        self.label_get_user.setStyleSheet("color:red")
        self.label_get_user.setObjectName("label_get_user")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 250, 251, 71))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 212, 241, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        SecondWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(SecondWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        SecondWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(SecondWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SecondWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, SecondWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SecondWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("SecondWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_user.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "User:"))
        self.label_get_user.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "UserFromFirstWindow"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "GetItButNeedUserFromFirstWindow"))


class SecondWindowView(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_SecondWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.label_get_user.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    sw = SecondWindowView()
    sw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конструктор, т.е. метод `__init__` выполняется **`ОДИН`** раз при инициализации.

Да, вы присвоили `label_get_user` новое значение:

```
self.sw.label_get_user.setText(val)
```

но `lineEdit` и не догадывается, что надо взять значение из `label_get_user`,
помогите ему это сделать:

```
self.sw.lineEdit.setText(self.sw.label_get_user.text())     # +++
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from q1334359_SecondWindow import SecondWindowView


class Ui_FirstWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, FirstWindow):
        FirstWindow.setObjectName("FirstWindow")
        FirstWindow.resize(313, 375)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(FirstWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 60, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 200, 141, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        FirstWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(FirstWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        FirstWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(FirstWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FirstWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, FirstWindow):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       FirstWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("FirstWindow", "MainWindow"))
       self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("FirstWindow", "User1"))
       self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("FirstWindow", "User2"))
       self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("FirstWindow", "User3"))
       self.pushButton.setText(_translate("FirstWindow", "SendData"))


class FirstWindowView(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_FirstWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_second_window)

    def open_second_window(self):
        self.sw = SecondWindowView()                     
        val = self.comboBox.currentText()
        self.sw.label_get_user.setText(val)

        self.sw.lineEdit.setText(self.sw.label_get_user.text())     # +++
       
        self.hide()
        self.sw.show()
        print('Hello self.sw.label_get_user') #


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    fw = FirstWindowView()
    fw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! а если нужно передать это значение не в lineEdit, а в переменную заданную во втором окне, этот метод подойдет?(например передать это значение в setFilter QTableView)

Comment: @ДензаЧеловечище все можно сделать. Вы приложили пример, из которого я понял, что надо изменить и `lineEdit` и предоставил для вас возможное решение. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас возникают другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, приложите пример, который демонстрирует проблему и понятно расскажите что вы хотите сделать.